# sharepoint 2013 anonymous 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: anonymous-authentication

I have a web application that i created on sharepoint 2013

I have enabled anonymous access according to this link:

Central Admin -> Manage web application -> Authentication Providers -> Default -> Enable Anonymous users (checked)

Went into the web app under Site Permissions and set Anonymous access to: "Entire Web Site"
but still when i click on each list or libraries credential pop up open and anonymous user got 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Comment: Check IIS that Anonymous access is enabled.

Comment: yes it is enabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable anonymous access to your site (or parts of it), you still need to deactivate “**Limited-access user permission lockdown mode**” Site Collection Feature if you want those users to be able to dive into Lists or Libraries.

1. Enable anonymous access in “Authentication Providers” (Central Administration > Application Management)
2. Grant rights to anonymous users in Site permissions
3. Grant rights to specific library (if applicable)
4. Disable the “Limited-access user permission lockdown mode” Site Collection Feature

Comment: It is a publishing site and I can not see that feature!

Comment: Are you looking at Site features or Site Collection features? It is available in site collection features.

Comment: You save my day,Thank you so much I was looking in Site features.

Comment: Glad it helped!