# Sharepoint Server 2013 REST API returns 401 by calling 'FieldValuesAsHtml' in anonymous access

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, access

I've followed the steps from the following answer: [sharepoint 2013 anonymous 401 UNAUTHORIZED](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142640/sharepoint-2013-anonymous-401-unauthorized])[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbAxA.png)

However, it works partially for me. The REST calls works when I try to access basic information from any list, but when I call 'FieldsValuesAsHtml' endpoint, the response is 401 Unauthorized.

[image]

Comment: If I may ask, where are you executing this rest call from? The client browser? If so are you using IE or Chrome? I am wondering if its a cross domain problem.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome. The exception occurs only when calling 'FieldsValuesAsHtml' endpoints. Other endpoints works fine.

Comment: Could I ask you to try to do the exact same thing in IE? Let me know if it works there. If it does than I will explain what is happening

Comment: Same exception in IE. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve the problem. In order to 'FieldValuesAsHtml' endpoints get to work with both Anonymous and registered users, you have to make the request with `POST` method and empty body passing the header `X-RequestDigest` and it's value.

I was able to get the header value from this endpoint: `/_api/contextinfo`. Just be sure to call this before every 'FieldValuesAsHtml' requests.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the following REST API works or not.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items(28)
```

And then check the REST API below.

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items(28)?$expand=FieldValuesAsHtml
```